# Why double b=nextafter(0., 1.) is 0.000000e+00 for float type?

Tags: c, math, cmath

I found the result of `nextafter(0., 1.)` with data type **`double`** and **`float`** are not the same.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double a;
    float b;
    a=nextafter(0., 1.);
    b=nextafter(0., 1.);
    printf("default %e\n",nextafter(0., 1.));
    printf("double %e\n",a); //double 4.940656e-324
    printf("float %e\n",b); //float 0.000000e+00
    return 0;
}
```

Why the smallest `float` bigger than 0.0 is 0.000000e+00 ?

Comment: `nextafter` returns a very small `double`, and it becomes `0` when converted into a `float`. You need to use `nextafterf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `nextafter(0., 1.)` and store the result in a `float`, implicit type conversion happens. The function returns the smallest positive subnormal `double`, which is 4.940656 x 10⁻³²⁴. This value is then rounded to `float`, but it's too small to be represented as a `float`, leading to zero.

To get the correct `float` result, you should use `nextafterf(0.f, 1.f)`:

```c
float b = nextafterf(0.f, 1.f);
```

This will give you the smallest positive subnormal `float`.

Answer (score 1):

[`nextafter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter) returns a `double` (a very small one in this case).
When it is converted to `float` to assign to `b`, it gets rounded to `0`.

Instead you should use **`nextafterf`**, which is the **`float`** counterpart:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a = nextafter (0., 1.);
    float  b = nextafterf(0.f, 1.f);   // <---- here
    printf("double %e\n", a);
    printf("float  %e\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
double 4.940656e-324
float  1.401298e-45
```